# angular 2 md radio buttons

Tags: angular2

Привет, есть некая группа Md-radio-button'ов, некоторые из них `[disabled]`, как добавить текст к именно к тем, которые `[disabled]`.
Вот планкер из прошлого вопроса:

> https://plnkr.co/edit/ufz70Kx89YtWLglFPfck?p=preview

Пытаюсь сделать с помощью *ngIf, но не знаю, как поймать значение отключенной кнопки:

```
 <div class="block2">
  <md-radio-group class="delivery-addresses-list" [(ngModel)]="selectedCopyCountry">
    <md-radio-button *ngFor="let country of copycountries; let i = index" value="{{i}}" class="red" [disabled]="hasCountry(country)">
  <span>{{country.name}}</span>

      <span *ngIf="disabled">Choose another country</span>

     <br>
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По тому же условию, по которому дизейблится радио:

```
<span *ngIf="hasCountry(country)">Choose another country</span>
```

Но такие вещи лучше делать через `css` чтобы не выполнять лишних операций:

```
<md-radio-button *ngFor="let country of copycountries; let i = index" value="{{i}}" class="red" [disabled]="hasCountry(country)">
<span>{{country.name}}</span>
  <span>Choose another country</span>
  <br>
</md-radio-button>
```

css:

```
md-radio-button span { display: none }
md-radio-button[disabled] span { display: inline-block }
```

Comment: попробовал и так и так, не работает, а если делать через *ngIf - то он скрывает все элементы

Comment: извиняюсь, не работает через ngIf, через CSS работает, но было бы интересно узнать как работает через ngIF

Comment: @shoopik, пробовал на вашем планкере - работает

Comment: хм, и правда, в планкере работает, но локально почему-то не хочет

Answer (score 1):

Ты забыл про ref-ы `#but` в примере ниже.
Вот теория https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

```
<div class="block2">
   <md-radio-group class="delivery-addresses-list" 
       [(ngModel)]="selectedCopyCountry">
    <md-radio-button #but *ngFor="let country of copycountries; let i = index" value="{{i}}" class="red" [disabled]="hasCountry(country)">
    <span>{{country.name}}</span>

      <span *ngIf="but.disabled">Choose another country</span>

     <br>
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)